# Origin of SR Energy and 4-momentum Norm

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, metric-tensor, vectors

I've just started reading Sean M. Carroll's "Introduction to General Relativity: Spacetime and Geometry," and I've gotten hung up on the following after wading through the preliminaries on vectors, duals, and tensors:

On page 31-32, in section 1.9: Energy and Momentum, he asserts that acting on the four-momentum of a particle at rest can give us the components in moving frame:

If the four-momentum vector is defined by

$$
U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\tag{1.99}
$$
$$
p^\mu = mU^\mu \tag{1.101}
$$
And a Lorentz transformation of a particle moving with three-velocity $v=dx/dt$ along the x-axis gives us:
$$
p^\mu =(\gamma m, v \gamma m, 0, 0) \tag{1.102}
$$
Where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$, then we get the following, which I don't understand:

"For small $v$, this gives $p^0=m+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ (what we usually think of as rest energy plus kinetic energy) and $p^1=mv$ (what we usually think of as Newtonian momentum). Outside this approximation, we can simply write
$$
p_\mu p^\mu=-m^2\tag{1.103}
$$
or
$$
E=\sqrt{m^2-\textbf{p}^2}\tag{1.104}
$$
Where $\textbf{p}^2=\delta_{ij}p^ip^j$"

---

So, I understand that a Lorentz transformation that acts only on the x-axis will give us these starting components. Obviously $p^0$ will be attenuated by the Lorentz factor, as it is no longer the "rest mass," and $p^1$ will be increased to the momentum along the x-axis.

However, my intuition for vectors and dual vectors comes from theoretical chemistry, so I'm used to bra/ket notation, and everything being fairly firmly rooted in matrices and linear algebra. I know that with tensors in this book and in this subject there are further abstractions where thinking of rows and columns is no longer correct, but since we're working with a vector given to us as $p^\mu =(\gamma m, v \gamma m, 0, 0)$, I hope I'm in the right by thinking along the lines:

$p_\mu p^\mu$ is the norm of $p_\mu$, an inner product of $p_\mu$ with itself, as in $\eta_{\mu v}p^v p_\mu $, and therefore (given our metric) of the form $$p_\mu p^\mu=(\gamma m, v \gamma m, 0, 0)\begin{pmatrix}
-\gamma m\\v \gamma m\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=-\gamma^2 m^2+v^2 \gamma^2 m^2-v \gamma^2 m^2+v \gamma^2 m^2=-\gamma^2 m^2+v^2 \gamma^2 m^2$$
Now
$$
p_\mu p^\mu=\gamma^2 (-m^2+v^2 m^2)
$$
I can see how the $-m^2$ arises, but not how it is the only term. Furthermore, I don't see how this is an equivalent statement to
$$
E=\sqrt{m^2+\textbf{p}^2}
$$

On a related point, the comment about $p^0=m+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and $p^1=mv$ seems to me misleading, because with the condition "for small $v$" here meaning $v\rightarrow0$ implies that $p^0$ might as well also equal $m+\frac{1}{2}mv^\frac{1}{3}$ or $m+\frac{1}{2}mv^{3.2}$, since the condition of vanishing $v$ makes that second term pointless. Likewise for $p^1=mv$, would it not be true that this observation that a small $v$ approximation here returns familiar terms is arbitrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct that $p_\mu p^\mu = \gamma^2(-m^2 + v^2 m^2)$. Since $\gamma = (1-v^2)^{-1/2}$, and $-m^2 + v^2 m^2 = -(1-v^2)m^2$, the $\gamma^2$ cancels with the $(1-v^2)$ and we are left with just $-m^2$.

Furthermore, by definition $E = p^0$, so

$$ -m^2 = p^\mu p_\mu = -p^0 p_0 + \mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{p} = -E^2 + \mathbf{p}^2$$

We can rearrange that to yield $E = \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 +m^2}$.

Finally, no, $v \to 0$ does not make the second term "pointless". The kinetic energy of the body equals its total energy ($p^0$) minus its rest energy ($m$). It also, as we know, is approximately equal to $\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ when $v$ is small. If special relativity predicted that the leading term in $p^0 - m$ was something other than $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ for small $v$, for example $\frac{1}{2}mv^{1/3}$, then the theory would be in serious trouble. Luckily, the Taylor expansion of $(1-v^2)^{-1/2} - 1$ around $v = 0$ does indeed yield $\frac{1}{2}v^2$ as the leading term.

Comment: Thank you Brian! This is very helpful. In particular, the application of the knowledge "The kinetic energy of the body equals its total energy (p0) minus its rest energy (m)" went unstated in the text, and so I don't think I ever would have thought to apply that! :)